# Why can fields containing mutable references be implicitly borrowed at coercion sites?

Tags: rust

I am having trouble understanding why the following code compiles.

```
struct Wrapper<'a, T> {
    inner: &'a mut T
}

fn get<'a, T>(w: &'a mut Wrapper<'a, T>) -> &'a mut T {
    w.inner
}
```

According to the language reference, field expressions (like `w.inner`) are place expressions, and using a place expression in a value expression context (like the return value of a function) [should move the value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#moved-and-copied-types). Since mutable references don't implement `Copy`, this would result in a compiler error about moving out of `w`. Indeed, we *can* get such an error if we modify `get` slightly:

```
fn get<'a, T>(w: &'a mut Wrapper<'a, T>) -> &'a mut T {
    let x = w.inner;
    x
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `w.inner` which is behind a mutable reference
 --> src/lib.rs:6:13
  |
6 |     let x = w.inner;
  |             ^^^^^^^
  |             |
  |             move occurs because `w.inner` has type `&mut T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |             help: consider borrowing here: `&w.inner`
```

However, when we return `w.inner` directly, the language apparently implicitly reborrows it for us. Furthermore, the example above will *also* compile if we give `x` an explicit type annotation as `&mut T`. I know that function returns and annotated let statements are coercion sites whereas unannotated let statements are not, so I assume this is due to some kind of coercion? But I don't see how coercion can result in an implicit borrow like this.

(To be clear, I'm aware that there's nothing *conceptually* wrong with this code. If we just explicitly borrow `w.inner` before returning it then it all makes perfect sense to me. I'm just confused about what aspect of the language semantics allows us to omit that explicit borrow.)